# How to partial-update a jsonb datas column using pg-promise helpers, in a multi-row update?

Tags: pg-promise

How to partial-update a jsonb datas column using pg-promise helpers, in a multi-row update?

For example, I got this columns in a table person :
'id', 'name', 'age', 'other'
with 'other' a jsonb column like '{ gender: 'mal', weight: 75, height: 150 }'

I got to update 10 person whos name is 'Jane' to gender 'fem', without touching others fields in 'other'. How can I do that ?
I've try something like

```
// column sets
// adding a cast:jsonb see issue https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/514
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['?name', { name: 'other', cast: 'jsonb' }], {table: 'person'});

// values sets
const dataMulti = mydatas.map(d => {
 name: d.name,
 others: { gender: 'fem' }
})

// query
const query = pgp.helpers.update(dataMulti, cs) + ' WHERE t.name = "jane"';
return db.any(query, [])
```

But it change 'other' of all 'jane' to { gender: 'fem' }. How to do a partial update only ?

Regards

Comment: You should instead look into how to update individual columns inside JSON with ProgreSQL in general. Library `pg-promise` will just execute whatever you give it.

Comment: Also, you can only update an individual JSON column with a single-row update query. But multi-row update queries do not support such things, AFAIK.

Comment: Ok I used to resolve partial update using jsonb_set.